# Change Arrays in DataFrame to values

Tags: python, dataframe

After some operations I ended up with a dataframe with arrays as elements. How would I change these arrays into values?

Here is what I have:

```
                         X   ...                        Z
0                      [0.0]  ...    [-0.00481000481000482]
1  [-0.00047415836889519447]  ...    [-0.00616405879563775]
```

And this is what I want:

```
                         X   ...                        Z
0                       0.0  ...      -0.00481000481000482
1    -0.00047415836889519447  ...     -0.00616405879563775
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html). If your dataframe is `df`, then

```
df.applymap(lambda c: c[0])
```

applies the function taking the item at index 0, to each cell in the dataframe.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you have lists and variables in the same columns.. youll need to check for instance of list and then replace it.

```
def f(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):   
        return x[0]
    return x
df1['x'],df1['z'] = df1['x'].map(f),df1['z'].map(f)
```